# Abstract class in simultaneous coding

Tags: project, abstract

In my understanding,abstract class is usually used for some common methods for different class to be implemented differently .

Is there another use for it in a group project,so that one person can use the unfinished method of the other class and will not get an error like function not found?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using classes and interfaces to refer to the unfinished code (being developed in parallel by other developer) looks cleaner than just having a stub for that code.

This approach also allows easier dependency injection during tests as the testing mock (derived from the abstract class or implementing the agreed interface) can usually be substituted without any specific tricks.